# LinkedIn request from one account to another LinkedIn account using flutter

Tags: flutter, button, request, connection, linkedin-api

So my problem is how do you make a request from one LinkedIn account to another LinkedIn account by pressing a button in flutter. I couldn't find any LinkedIn connection request API in flutter.

Comment: The question is related to Linkedin API, not Flutter, please post with proper tags to get good answers

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.